# A query with a subquery returns neither data nor errors when run from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query to MSSQL database prepared. When executed in Manager, it works perfectly fine, but apparently it doesn't return any rows to PHP script. The most problematic part is probably this column:

```sql
Difference = t0.col1 - ISNULL((SELECT t1.col1 FROM table AS t1 WHERE t1.date =
(SELECT MAX(t2.date) FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.date < t0.date)), 0)
```

Or it could be this:

```sql
(SELECT NORMA FROM base2.dbo.ODB_S_PO WHERE <condition>)
```

Can I use subqueries when using PHP with MS SQL? Can those queries point to different databases? Can I line up several statements in one query from PHP, such as defining a variable?

EDIT: Posting full query:

```sql
SELECT t0.TA_DATA,
col1+' '+col2,
t0.TA_STAN_LICZNIKA,
Difference = t0.TA_STAN_LICZNIKA - ISNULL((SELECT t1.TA_STAN_LICZNIKA FROM tab1 AS t1 WHERE t1.TA_DATA =
(SELECT MAX(t2.TA_DATA) FROM tab1 AS t2 WHERE t2.TA_DATA < t0.TA_DATA AND t2.TA_ID_PJ = '03102')), 0),
t0.TA_ILE,
(SELECT NORMA FROM db2.dbo.ODB_S_PO WHERE KOD = '03102')
FROM tab1 AS t0
INNER JOIN tab2 ON t0.TA_ID_KI = KI_ID
WHERE t0.TA_ID_PJ = '03102' ORDER BY t0.TA_DATA DESC
```

This is the full query. Using one database I am referring to the same table three times to calculate the difference and trying to access another database to get a certain variable. Leaving out the select from another database and getting the variable in a separate query doesn't help.

EDIT2: I tried using the account used in Management Studio, as well as the one dedicated for the web interface. Per suggestion, here's the (almost) full PHP script:

```php
$car = $_POST['id'];
include '../bd.php';
$nazwa_hosta = '';
$username = '';
$passwd = '';
$baza = 'gps';
//print_r($_POST);
$res_dbase = new BD($nazwa_hosta, $username, $passwd, $baza);
$res_dbase->bd_polacz();
$query = "SELECT MARKA, NRR,
 CONVERT(varchar, [DATE_TIME], 104) AS Dzien,
 DATE_TIME,
 CAST(DISTANCE AS FLOAT) / 1000 AS DIST,
 Diff = CAST(t0.DISTANCE - ISNULL((SELECT t1.DISTANCE FROM reports AS t1 WHERE t1.ID =
(SELECT MAX(t2.ID) FROM reports AS t2 WHERE t2.ID < t0.ID AND t2.DEVICE_ID = t0.DEVICE_ID)), 0) AS FLOAT) / 1000,
 IGNITION_SWITCH_STATE AS Stac,
 SPEED,
 KI_NAZWISKO+' '+KI_IMIE AS Kier
 FROM Mediator.dbo.ODB_S_PO AS pojlist
 INNER JOIN mikrostacje.dbo.MS_BLACK_BOX ON pojlist.KOD = '0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, BB_ID_PJ)
 INNER JOIN gps.dbo.reports AS t0 ON DEVICE_ID = BB_ID
 INNER JOIN mikrostacje.dbo.MS_KIEROWCA ON KI_ID = (SELECT IDK_ID_KI FROM mikrostacje.dbo.MS_ID_KARTA_KIEROWCA WHERE IDK_RFID_NO = RFID)
 WHERE KOD = '$car'
 ORDER BY DATE_TIME DESC";
echo $query."<br />";
if(!($res_dbase->bd_zapytaj($query))) //the code fails here - otherwise I wouldn't get any message from the server. And the only message I get is that it changes the context to 'gps'
{
    echo mssql_get_last_message();
}
$marka = "";
$nrr = "";
$result = "";
while(false !== ($row = $res_dbase->bd_pobierzTabliceAsocjacyjna()))
{
    $marka = $row['MARKA'];
    $nrr = $row['NRR'];
    $result .= "<tr><td>".$row['Dzien']."</td><td>".$row['DATE_TIME']."</td><td>".$row['Dist']."</td><td>".$row['Diff']."</td><td>".$row['Stac']."</td><td>".$row['Kier']."</td></tr>".PHP_EOL;
}
$head = "<div style='text-align: center; margin: auto'><b>$nrr $marka</b><table>";
$result .= "</table></div>";
$echo = remove_pl($head.$result, "latin2"); // Removing Polish characters, since the target is encoded in Windows-1250
echo $echo;
```

Comment: format your question to make it readable

Comment: Sub-queries are of course allowed if they are well written and you have the rights necessary to access all the resources involved. Can you post the entire query?

Comment: In general, if a query doesn't return *rows*, you shouldn't be looking for issues with particular *columns*. On the other hand, if the expression for a column causes an error, that does result in no rows returned too. So, does they query produce any errors? Have you tried running it in e.g. Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. I've been checking the query in Management Studio, that's where I designed it before including in PHP code.

Comment: The problem remains unsolved. Query returns no results nor errors, and while executed in Management Studio works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you test your script in SSMS under the same user as when you ran it from PHP? It's a bit strange that there was no error either, but maybe there's middle-tier software that is configured to consume errors coming from the database server? I know it sounds like a wild guess (which it really is), but your situation *is* rather strange too.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe the issue is in your PHP code. You might want to post the relevant part of it too.

Comment: I edited the title of your post to make it more specific, but please feel free to roll it back if you think the original one suited you better.